# How to implement rollback in nodejs with async module?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I've been working on nodejs since last 2 months and this is the problem i come across while handling with async module. Sometimes on some error async error calls error from the middle of async tasks.Consider this code :

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var async = require('async');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  database: 'test',
  password: '12345'
});

var chairArr = ['Red', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Voilet', 'Brown'];
var inventoryName = "Chairs";
addInventory(inventoryName, chairArr, function(err, result) {
  if(err) {
    console.log("Err : "+err);
  }
  console.log("Successfully added an inventory");
});


function addInventory(inventoryName, chairArr, callback) {
  var sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tb_inventory(name, added_on) VALUES( ?, NOW())";
  connection.query(sqlQuery, [inventoryName], function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      return callback(err, null);
    }
    var inventoryId = result.insertId;
    var tasks = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < chairArr.length; i++) {
      tasks.push(addChair.bind(null, inventoryId, chairArr[i]));
    }
    async.parallel(tasks, function(taskErr, taskRes) {
      if(taskErr) {
        return callback(taskErr, null);
      }
      callback(null, result);
    });
  });
}

function addChair(inventoryId, chairColor, callback) {
  var sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tb_chairs(inventory_id, color) VALUES(?, ?)";
  connection.query(sqlQuery, [inventoryId, chairColor], function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      return callback(err, null);
    }
    callback(null, result);
  });
}
```

This simple program just inserts  into two tables tb_inventory and tb_chairs. My question is : Sometimes due to parameters from front-end or my mistake query does not execute and async parallel calls the error callback from that. Is there a way to rollback(i.e delete all the inserted entries in the table.) Can anyone tell me how to implement that in the error callback(i.e track all the id's inserted and delete those?). Can we use `mysql transactions` globally?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#transactions)?

Comment: Yeah, the connection.beginTransaction takes a sequence of queries. But i'm not sure how would i implement a transaction among a series of function calls which may or may not involve querying database. I want to know if there is  some way to implement a rollback mechanism on failure.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever working with a series of functions, we can get a local connection from pool and pass that local connection in the functions called during the async call. Commit or rollback can be handled at the callback of the async call.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var async = require('async');

var dbPool = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  database: 'test',
  password: '12345',
  connectionLimit: 10
});

//var chairArr = ['Red', 'Green!++++++++++++++++!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!', 'Yellow', 'Voilet', 'Brown']; //Case where query fails due to VARCHAR(20) limit
var chairArr   = ['Red', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Voilet', 'Brown'];
var inventoryName = "SOME ITEM ";
dbPool.getConnection(function(conErr, localConnection) {
    localConnection.beginTransaction(function(transactionErr) {
      if(transactionErr)  {
          console.log("There was some error in begining transaction");
          return;
      }
      addInventory(localConnection, inventoryName, chairArr, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
          console.log("Err : "+err);
          return;
        }
        else {
          console.log("Successfully added an inventory");
        }
      });
    });
});


function addInventory(localConnection, inventoryName, chairArr, callback) {
  var sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tb_inventory(name, added_on) VALUES( ?, NOW())";
  localConnection.query(sqlQuery, [inventoryName], function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      return callback(err, null);
    }
    var inventoryId = result.insertId;
    var tasks = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < chairArr.length; i++) {
      tasks.push(addChair.bind(null, localConnection, inventoryId, chairArr[i]));
    }
    async.parallel(tasks, function(err, asyncRes) {
      if(err) {
        rollback(localConnection, function(rollErr, rollRes) {
          return callback(err, null);
        });
      }
      else {
        localConnection.commit(function(commitErr, commitRes) {
          console.log("transaction succeded");
          return callback(null, "Success");
        });
      }
    });
  });
}

function addChair(localConnection, inventoryId, chairColor, callback) {
  var sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tb_chairs(inventory_id, color) VALUES(?, ?)";
  localConnection.query(sqlQuery, [inventoryId, chairColor], function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      return callback(err, null);
    }
    callback(null, result);
  });
}

function rollback(localConnection, callback) {
  localConnection.rollback(function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("ROLLBACK Failed");
      return callback(err, null);
    }
    console.log("ROLLBACK successful!");
    callback(null, result);
  });
}
```

I hope it helps.